# Unhanded rejection error :Transaction query already complete - knex, express.js

Tags: express, knex.js

I was trying to check for a value in a table first, and if it exists, delete a row in another table and insert this new data into that table.

I used a transaction with a select, del(), and a insert command

```js
db.transaction(trx => {
  return trx('users')
    .where({ username: user.username })
    .select('username')
    .returning('username')

    .then(retData => {
      retUserName = retData[0];

      db('profile')
        .where({ username: user.username })
        .del()
        .then(retData => {
          return trx
            .insert(profileData)
            .into('profile')
            .returning('*');
        });
    })
    .then(retData => {
      res.json({ ProfileData: profileData });
    })
    .then(trx.commit)
    .catch(trx.rollback);
}).catch(err => res.status(400).json('unable to create profile'));
```

I get this error Unhanded rejection error:Transaction query already completed

but the data hasn't been added to the table.

Answer (score 16):

You are returning promise from transaction handler callback, which causes transaction to automatically committed / rolled back depending if returned promise resolves / rejects.

https://knexjs.org/guide/transactions.html

> Throwing an error directly from the transaction handler function
> automatically rolls back the transaction, same as returning a rejected
> promise.
>
> Notice that if a promise is not returned within the handler, it is up
> to you to ensure trx.commit, or trx.rollback are called, otherwise the
> transaction connection will hang.

In your code you are mixing those two different ways to use transactions, which causes it to be committed / rolledback twice.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into different situation but same error. Perhaps it helps someone.

```
knex.transaction(async (t) => {
...
```

Using async function causes the same effect..

**This worked**

```
knex.transaction((t) => {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `up` and `down` are async functions, make sure to await the `knex.transaction` call.

**Problem**: missing `await`

```
export async function up(knex: Knex): Promise<void> {
    knex.transaction(async (tx) => {});
//  ^ await is missing. This will error
}
```

**Solution**: use `await`

```
export async function up(knex: Knex): Promise<void> {
    await knex.transaction(async (tx) => {});
//  The `up` function will wait until the transaction finishes
}
```